# hadoop map task timeout

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, nutch

Recently, I got a map task attempt timeout error. I have changed `mapreduce.task.timeout=1800000` or more time, but my problem still occur.

Could anyone help me about this?

Background:
I used Nutch to crawl website, in `generate` stage map task failed. Each part in crawldb is about 10~20G. Resources(memory and cpu cores) between nodes have a big gap.

Comment: Can you add sample code which you tried?

Answer (score 0):

10-20 GB per part of the CrawlDb sounds a lot, but it also depends whether parts are splittable (cf. `mapreduce.input.fileinputformat.split.minsize` and `mapreduce.output.fileoutputformat.compress.codec`).

My "favorite" settings for the CrawlDb are

- use [BZip2Codec](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/current/api/org/apache/hadoop/io/compress/BZip2Codec.html) (splittable) and
- limit the part size to 20 million URLs resp. ~1GB (bzip2 compressed) by setting the number of reducers accordingly via `-Dmapreduce.job.reduces=XXX` to all jobs writing the CrawlDb (updatedb, inject, mergedb, dedup)

However, to find the optimal options for your cluster setup and hardware may require some experiments. Just make sure that no task takes too long and dominates the job execution time.

Comment: Thank you very much. Could you tell me why some map task got failed which even don't start to get input? It just like blocked.

Comment: I have set a param `-D mapreduce.output.fileoutputformat.compress.type=BLOCK`

Comment: Yes, of course, BLOCK is correct. RECORD would be nonsense given that CrawlDb records are quite small.
The reason why map tasks fail should be in the task (attempt) logs.